# Documentation for ios 7 app identifier (or whatever is called) like 6FD70F29-E007-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Tags: ios, app-id

I am porting an existing Android application to iOS and I am new to iOS

The application is installed on the iOS device with this path:

`/var/mobile/Applications/6FD70F29-E007-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/myApp.app`

Where the `6FD70F29-E007-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` is automatically generated by xCode.

I read a lot through the docs but I am a bit confused. How is that part called? App identifier, App ID, APP_UUID? Where is it documented? I would like to know if it changes across devices, across re-installations on the same device, after a factory reset, on app updates etc.

Thanks and sorry if it is a noob question!

Comment: Are you developing app for jail break devices? because if it will be app store app the path totally irrelevant. what is the reason you want to learn where it is deployed?

Comment: I need to access the file system consistently and save file paths to database. Not jailbreak devices

Comment: ah i see. as i said if your app will be on app store you can't access to filesystem directly with giving path. you can use sqllite or core data to keep your records. search for IOS core data tutorial you will find many. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: That's not quite correct. You can access the file system to save and load files, however you cannot move above the root of your app's sandboxed directories - so you can safely use file paths with iOS mapping the access between your sandboxed directories and the actual file system.  For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351535/saving-text-file-to-documents-directory-in-ios-7?answertab=active#tab-top and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907381/what-is-the-documents-directory-nsdocumentdirectory

Comment: @Paulw11 I agree, I will use the Documents folder and the tmp folder to manage my files.