# How do I save a swift array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am creating an app in Swift that manages tasks based off of priority. I currently place the tasks into an array. Does anybody know how I can save this array so that when I open the app I will still be able to access the data?

Comment: Check out the answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233067/simple-persistent-storage-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults.

Save array:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(myArray, forKey: "myarray")
defaults.synchronize()
```

Read array:

```
myArray = defaults.dataForKey("myarray") as Array
```

Comment: the save array seems to be working but when i put in the code to read the array i get this error:  Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'String'

Comment: While this is a good starting point for a newcomer, please be aware that `NSUserDefaults` is by no means a replacement for a full-fledged persisting data store. When you're more comfortable, you should move on to real solutions like Core Data.