# How do I write a string to a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I have a `.txt` file with a small password in it. I would like to change that file's text. How can I do that? I can get the file's text using :

```
 NSString *passWord = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"password" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

But I can't seem to find a way to replace the contents of the file with a string.

Comment: Show what you have tried. Keep in mind that you can't write to a file in the app bundle. It's read-only.

Comment: Try to use `UTF-16` encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to remove old file and create new one.
**Removing existing file**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.txt"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
}
```

To crate new file with your new password write password data while creating file as:

```
[createFileAtPath:path contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil]
```

Comment: How does your code actually write the string to a file?

Comment: @Nirmal Choudhari Can't I just use the `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"password" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];` for the path?

Comment: @XtremeHek3r No. As I said, the bundle is read-only. You can't write to it.

Comment: No You have to copy file from your bundle to document directory after app install to work this. You can read file from main bundle but cant write them. thats why.

Comment: @XtremeHek3r i think This like helpful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351535/saving-text-file-to-documents-directory-in-ios-7

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I thought I could write data to the txt file in the project but I guess not. Well anyway, I decided to re-do my project and write a file to Documents directory instead.